# content disappearing when navbar is pushed up

Tags: javascript, html, navbar

I want the navbar to disappear right after the website has loaded

```
window.onload = function(){
        setTimeout(function (){
            document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-500px";
        },2000);
    }``
```

The rest of the content on my website (Cards generated with Bootstrap) disappears.
They are just not visible, it's just the nav, an image and the footer left without any empty space in between, so it totally removes them, as if they weren't in the code.

When removing the brackets after "function" the content appears, but pushing up the navbar doesn't work anymore.

Using `display: none` doesn't change the issue.
Neither does hiding it and changing the pointer

Comment: why not just hide element with `document.getElementById("navbar").style.display = "none";`

Answer (score 0):

How about instead of changing the navbars position, which will shift everything else with it, you just hide it and disable pointer events as such:

```js
window.onload = function(){
    setTimeout(function (){
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.opacity = 0
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.pointerEvents = "none";
    },2000);
}
```

The navbar will still be there so no positioning of other elements on the page will be affected, but it will be invisible and if they try to click on the former navbar, nothing will work.

You could also use `display: none;`, but that would shift the position of everything else on the page.

Comment: The problem is that somehow, as soon as it says function"()"(with the 2 brackets), the Bootstrap Cards all vanish. They are not just invisible, it is just the nav, an image and the footer left, so it totally removes them, as if they weren´t in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: none;`  instead

```
window.onload = function(){
    setTimeout(function (){
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.display = "none";
  },2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution to the problem was removing the

```
window.onload = function(){

}
```

around the Timeout and adding a different condition